# Screen annotation software to draw on any app in OSX

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I want to draw on any app pdfs, videos, code. It would be helpful to aid in demonstration in a class setting for me. Do you know if any such app exists that does not require an external pen i.e. using mouse or trackpad to draw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [Snappy App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snappyapp/id512617038?mt=12) - it allows you to grab any part of your screen and float it above the screen - then you can draw on it, change its transparency, shrink it down, whatever. There's a free version which does more or less all you'd want and the in-app purchases are very cheap (you need an in-app to draw on things).
I've also just recently been introduced to https://presentify.compzets.com/ which takes a different approach but might also meet the requirements.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a screen annotation app that is unobtrusive and fast, check out [DemoPro](http://www.demoproapp.com) . DemoPro lets you configure hotkeys to draw on the screen, which is very convenient if you are doing live demonstrations. It also includes a countdown timer which can be useful for breakout sessions, exams, etc.

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME!

Comment: This is the best one as of Sept. 2020. I am a previous ink2go user (for many years) and DemoPro is waaay better.

Answer (score 3):

This software does exactly that http://ink2go.org/ allows the user to draw on any application. It also allows for screen recording and other features. I suggest if you are looking for other alternatives to search for "screen annotation software for mac" that gave me more precise results.

Comment: I purchased it recently, and sent a question to support about a but. No reply for weeks. It is unfortunate because ink2go is  such a good app.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for a nice mouse highlight tool for 2 hours and find something different but really nice!

http://screenbrush.imagestudiopro.com/

With the free version, you can easily draw on your screen and also highlight the screen with the shift key.

If you're still looking for a cursor highlighter I've found Mouse Locator App  (http://www.2point5fish.com/)

But it's not very polished and has few configuration options

When I found Screenbrush it already made my day and stop searching, but I read on a forum post somewhere that if you change your search query to "mac Screen annotation software" you will have more results, maybe it helps in finding a better Cursor highlighter app.

Good luck!

Comment: You can install ScreenBrush through the Apple App Store:  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/screenbrush/id1233965871

Answer (score 1):

[Screenink](http://www.swordsoft.idv.tw/screenink/) is also another app that will take a screenshot for the moment and allow you to draw on that, annotate and save.

Answer (score 1):

A friend uses [Highlight](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/highlight/id572867415?mt=12&at=11l73K&ct=twitter).

You have to define your own hotkey to turn it on and off.

Comment: This one did exactly what I wanted. It is cheap, but no trial. Anyway - allows just to draw on screen after pressing hotkey, that's it but that is all I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you were looking for. I think you should check out DemPro.

it is a Mac annotation app.