# Windows Zoomit like tool from mac

Tags: macos, zoom

I have been using zoomit on windows. With that tool: I can write on screen, zoom screen, draw shapes on screen while doing presentation. Also, I can run a stopwatch for break during presentation. Blacken, whiten the screen. Is there such kind of tool for Mac? I saw zoomit for mac and its absolutely rubbish which only zooms and doesn't nothing extra like window's zoomit.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx

Comment: Which application are you using when doing presentations? Powerpoint, Keynote or something else?

Comment: @patrix have a look at the screenshots http://s1313.photobucket.com/user/cooldudeabhi/library/Zoomit

I use simple tools like text editor & terminal to do programming based demos(presentations).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen annotation software to draw on any app in OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/172046/screen-annotation-software-to-draw-on-any-app-in-osx)

Answer (score 1):

There's a great app on Apple Store named "Draw on My Screen EZ". [Link](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/draw-on-my-screen-ez/id1082177879?mt=12) to app