# PDF annotator with pen support that works well

Tags: pdf, drawing

Is there a PDF viewer for Mac that supports drawing freehand lines in a way that allows you to actually write text? The built-in Preview app *almost* supports it but it's completely unusable because if you try to draw over an existing line (e.g. if you draw an H, you first draw | and then -), then it just selects the existing line. Infuriating.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/172046/screen-annotation-software-to-draw-on-any-app-in-osx

Comment: That's not quite what I want - I want to *annotate* the PDF so that when I save it the annotations are included. I don't just want to draw ephemeral lines on the screen for a presentation or whatever.